# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on External Hard Drive, Operating System not found

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, system-installation

Had an External Hard Drive that had not installed any operating system on it previously, shrank part of it and then installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it, everything went fine but then when i restarted, tried to boot from my external hard drive, was presented with a "Operating System not found" message, any ideas what could be the problem? or how should I do it? I will provide any needed information

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could skip setting your external hdd as a device for keeping the Boot loader. It doesn't happen automatically. It is chosen separately at one of the beginning installation screens.

Here is the picture, as an example, in you case there must be your ext. drive chosen

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I did set it correctly (if I remember correctly), not sure how to make sure I did so or not